# iOS web app not working offline in homescreen app, but working in Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I have a basic `create-react-app` app that I tested on my iPhone 8 (through localhost). The service worker registers properly when using Safari, but after adding the app to my homescreen and launching from there, the service worker doesn't work and I get the "Safari could not load the page because your iPhone is not connected to the internet" message. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

For some reason, service workers work through localhost on iOS, but have weird behaviour unless they are hosted on an HTTPS host. I was able to fix this problem (and one other where an image wasn't loading after disappearing and reappearing) by hosting the production build on a DigitalOcean server.